# Java public Logger

Tags: java, logging

Is it allowed to make a single static class for your log?

```
public final class Log {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());

}
```

And call it whenever it's needed?

```
Log.LOGGER.info("Let's log something!");
```

Rather than add this single line of code on every class?

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());
```

I read information that you should initializes the Logger in every single class.

```
public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName());
```

Or what's the way to go? I prefer some static approuch rather than initializes the logger in every single class...

I tried it out, and the result is as follow.

*Preview:*

**Log**

```
public class Log {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());

}
```

**App**

```
final class App() {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }

    private static void start() {
        Log.LOGGER.info("Starting the application.");
    }

}
```

**Kernel**

```
public final class Kernel() {

    public static void preload() {
        Log.LOGGER.info("Preload kernel modules.");
    }

}
```

*Output:*

```
Aug 26, 2015 2:17:34 PM nl.nberlijn.powercontrol.App start
INFO: Starting the application.
Aug 26, 2015 2:17:34 PM nl.nberlijn.powercontrol.kernel.Kernel preload
INFO: Preload kernel modules.
```

Comment: You could go one step further by implementing `info()`, `error()`, etc in `Log`, so you can do `Log.info(...)`.

Comment: search for @slf4j annotation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow a similar approach I would suggest to use static methods for logging instead like in the following example :

```
 public final class Log {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());
    public void logError(String someText) {
       LOGGER.error(someText);
    }
    public static LogInfo(String someText) {
       LOGGER.info(someText);
    }
}
```

and then call it in your client classes simply with :

```
    private static void start() {
        LogInfo("Starting the application.");
    }
```

Of course before you need a static import :

```
import static com.yourpackage.Log.*
```

*It is an approach that could be followed, but I would prefer to inject the logger inside the components of your application that needs to log something, leaving things more decoupled ...*

Comment: When I do that the output will be always from the Log class: `Aug 26, 2015 2:31:59 PM nl.nberlijn.powercontrol.kernel.Log info
INFO: Starting the application.
Aug 26, 2015 2:31:59 PM nl.nberlijn.powercontrol.kernel.Log info
INFO: Preload kernel modules.`

Comment: Of course, you will need to pass the caller class if you need to ... Anyway as I've state in the answer it is better to go encapsulating the logger into the client class especially if you need to the log the caller ...

Comment: What do you mean with "encapsulating the logger into the client class", initializing the Logger variable in all the classes? Maybe you can give an example?

Comment: You can declare it as a property of the client class and inject it maybe with a dependency injection container

Comment: I'm trying to do that. Currently I made @Log annotation for the classes where I want to inject the Logger.

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed, but there's a reason people don't do this.

With the usual approach of having a separate logger for each class, you can filter your logging based on which packages and classes you want to see, at what level. That way you don't have to worry too much about whether to insert a call to the logger, you can keep it in even if you don't need it all the time, because you can filter it out. When there's a problem you can increase the log level for just those classes you're interested in. But with the single Log class approach you can't do that at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this:

```
public static final class Logger {
    public static Logger get() {
        return Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
Logger.get().log("Hello World!");
```

This will allow you preserve information such as the name of the logging class and won't require you to actually pass the calling class name as a parameter. I am not sure of the performance of getting the stacktrace on every call though, so this might not be efficient.